# How to use @JsonIdentityInfo with custom attribute serializer

Tags: java, jpa, jackson

I have a JPA entity with circular references to other entities. To solve the serialization issue this causes I have added the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation, like so:

```
private class Child {

  private long id;

  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
  private Parent parent;
}
```

This results in the following serialization:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "parent": 1
}
```

This would be fine normally, however I have a custom JsonSerializer on Parent.id attibute to encode its long id into a String. I would like this custom Serializer to be used by @JsonIdentityInfo.

How can I do that?

I have tried implementing a custom ObjectIdGenerator, but I can't figure out how to do it or if that's the way to go about this.

Comment: could u post the test code about these